# How to force g++ linker to load a symbols not being directly called - avoiding undefined reference

Tags: c++, sqlite, linker, namespaces, g++

The problem I'm facing is difficult to describe and explain, but let's try...

Enrivornment: Ubuntu, C++ and g++

So I have an hierarchy of c++ projects and namespaces:

`main`: My main program - that calls....

`objectaccess`: Access objects    (read, write, update, delete) - that calls...

`commonaccess`:          Encapsulate access to sqlite3 functions (sqlite3_open, sqlite3_exec,     etc.) - that calls...

`sqlite3.so`: The Sqlite3 library.

So, an example call code would be:

```
#include "objectaccess.hpp"
#include "commonaccess.hpp"

int main()
{
    int id = 10;
    myobjecttype mo = objectaccess::get(id);

}
```

At objectaccess I have:

```
#include "commonaccess.hpp"

namespace objectaccess {

    myobjecttype get(int id)
    {
        myobjecttype mo = commonaccess::getFromTableX(id);
        return mo;
    }
}
```

At commonaccess I have:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>

namespace commonaccess {

     myobjecttype getFromTableX(int id)
     {
         sqlite3_init(whatever...);
         sqlite3_exe(whatever...);

         myobjecttype retobject;
         retobject.whatever = data1;

         return retobject;
     }
}
```

The code runs fine and is tested, except for one problem. All three namespaces are in different projects delivering a dynamic library (`commonaccess.so` and `objectaccess.so`) except for the main program that returns a binary executable.

My problem is:

At main, if I make a call to any of commonaccess functions, I get the following errors on linking:

```
g++ -L"/home/workspace/objectaccess/Debug" 
-L"/home/workspace/commonaccess/Debug" 
-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -Xlinker -rpath="./" -o "test"  ./src/test.o   
-lsqlite3 -lobjectaccess -lcommonaccess
/home/workspace/commonaccess/Debug/libcommonaccess.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
/home/workspace/commonaccess/Debug/libcommonaccess.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_exec'
/home/workspace/commonaccess/Debug/libcommonaccess.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_free'
/home/workspace/commonaccess/Debug/libcommonaccess.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_errmsg'
/home/workspace/commonaccess/Debug/libcommonaccess.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
/home/workspace/commonaccess/Debug/libcommonaccess.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is simply solved adding at `main()` a call to any function of commonaccess, like:

```
#include "objectaccess.hpp"
#include "commonaccess.hpp"

int main()
{
    commonaccess::dummycall();

    int id = 10;
    myobjecttype mo = objectaccess::get(id);

}
```

Actually calling a dummy function is not desired, so:

a) Why the linker is not being able to solve these references without directly calling any of the `commonaccess` functions?

b) Why only adding a call to the lower hierarchy namespace in the main program "teaches" the linker about real reference to sqlite3 functions?

Comment: You really should be using `int main()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch the order of libraries being linked. GNU linker can't reorder them, nor keeps references to calls not used so far, so `-lsqlite3` is currently useless. Put it after the library that actually uses sqlite3 calls, something like `g++ -L"/home/workspace/objectaccess/Debug" -L"/home/workspace/commonaccess/Debug" -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -Xlinker -rpath="./" -o "test"  ./src/test.o -lobjectaccess -lcommonaccess -lsqlite3`

Comment: Anoter way is to use `-Wl,--start-group` etc. which will make the linker keep re-trying the libraries to resolve undefined references, instead of just doing a single pass

Comment: Actually I had tried '-lsqlite3' in all positions with no success. Only calling dummy is being able to compile.

Comment: make sure that _all_ libraries go in a proper order, that is `-lobjectaccess` goes first, then `-lcommonaccess`, then `-lsqlite3`. Also I would suggest you to link `-lsqlite3` while linking `commonaccess` and `-lcommonaccess` while linking `objectaccess`. Thus with a modern enough linker you can avoid the necessity of explicit specification of all involved libraries.

Comment: Or if you still get the error, provide a minimal compileable example, because I've just tested such an example (and it's compiled and linked indeed!), but perhaps your code has some specific which isn't covered by your explanations and our guessings